# Send multiple requests separate instead of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, promise

This is part of code (*code not mine, I can't understand how it's working, maybe it's called Promise, but I'm not sure*).

```
m = {
    mounted: function() {
        var e = this;
        this.$bus.on("buff-event", (function(t) {
            e.buff(t)
        }))
    },
    methods: {
        buff: function(e) {
            var t = this;
            this.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Motivating...");
            var n = '[{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[],"requestClass":"OtherPlayerService","requestMethod":"' + e + '","requestId":%%requestId%%}]';
            this.requestFaker.fetch(n).then((function(i) {
                i = (i = i.filter((function(t) {
                    return t.requestMethod == e
                }))[0]).responseData.filter((function(e) {
                    return void 0 === e.next_interaction_in && !e.is_self && (void 0 === e.accepted || 1 == e.accepted)
                })), n = [], _.forEach(i, (function(e) {
                    n.push('{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[' + e.player_id + '],"requestClass":"OtherPlayerService","requestMethod":"polivateRandomBuilding","requestId":%%requestId%%}')
                })), n.length ? (n = "[" + n.join(",") + "]", t.requestFaker.fetch(n).then((function() {
                    t.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Motivation success")
                }))) : t.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Nobody to motivate")
            }))
        }
    }
},
```

This code collecting data of users, store in to array and then pass it to the server. So it sending big array of all users in one request (it pushing all entries to array in this part `n.push('{"__class__":"ServerRequest"...`).

What I want to achieve is to send requests for each user one by one with some delays (for example 1 second delay between requests).

I've tried many ways to achieve it, but all unsuccessfully, I'm lack of knowledge about this programming language.

I've tried to use `setTimeout` functions in different ways, but all the time unsuccessfully:

```
methods: {
    buff: function(e) {
        var t = this;
        this.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Motivating...");
        var n = '[{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[],"requestClass":"OtherPlayerService","requestMethod":"' + e + '","requestId":%%requestId%%}]';
        this.requestFaker.fetch(n).then((function(i) {
            i = (i = i.filter((function(t) {
                return t.requestMethod == e
            }))[0]).responseData.filter((function(e) {
                return void 0 === e.next_interaction_in && !e.is_self && (void 0 === e.accepted || 1 == e.accepted)
            })), n = [], _.forEach(i, (function(e) {
                n.push('{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[' + e.player_id + '],"requestClass":"OtherPlayerService","requestMethod":"polivateRandomBuilding","requestId":%%requestId%%}')
            })), n.length ? 
            setTimeout((function() {
            (setTimeout((function() {n = "[" + n.join(",") + "]"}), 1000) , t.requestFaker.fetch(n).then((function() {
                t.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Motivation success")
            })))}), 1000)  : t.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Nobody to motivate")
        }))
    }
}
```

Also tried like this:

```
methods: {
    buff: function(e) {
        var t = this;
        this.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Motivating...");
        var n = '[{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[],"requestClass":"OtherPlayerService","requestMethod":"' + e + '","requestId":%%requestId%%}]';
        this.requestFaker.fetch(n).then((function(i) {
            i = (i = i.filter((function(t) {
                return t.requestMethod == e
            }))[0]).responseData.filter((function(e) {
                return void 0 === e.next_interaction_in && !e.is_self && (void 0 === e.accepted || 1 == e.accepted)
            })), n = [], _.forEach(i, (function(e) {
                n.push('{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[' + e.player_id + '],"requestClass":"OtherPlayerService","requestMethod":"polivateRandomBuilding","requestId":%%requestId%%}')
            })), n.length ? 
            setTimeout((function() {
            (n = "[" + n.join(",") + "]", t.requestFaker.fetch(n).then((function() {
                t.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Motivation success")
            })))}), 1000)  : t.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Nobody to motivate")
        }))
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

As per comment asked what is `%%requestId%%` - I found this part:

```
{
    key: "fetch",
    value: function(e) {
        function t(t) {
            return e.apply(this, arguments)
        }
        return t.toString = function() {
            return e.toString()
        }, t
    }((function(e) {
        for (var t = e;
            (t = e.replace("%%requestId%%", this.requestId)) !== e;) e = t, this.incRequestId();
        return fetch(gameVars.gatewayUrl, this.getHeadForFetchQuery(e)).then((function(e) {
            return e.json()
        }))
    }))
}
```

Comment: Are you using some templating engine? What is `%%requestId%%`?

Comment: @trincot thank you for your comment. I've updated question with details about `%%requestId%%"`. I have no idea what it means and why it's used here. I copy > pasted code between `{ }`,  but there is much bigger function, if this part is not enough I can paste here entire function.

Comment: What is this spaghetti code?

Comment: @DanZuzevich I can't understand it too, I thought maybe more experienced developers will understand and can help me to sort it out.

Comment: it's minified/uglified. where is it running, on the browser.?

Comment: @traynor yes, this is extension for browser. Is it possible to undo this "minify" to make it more clean?

Comment: so you mean to run it as an addon on the browser? actually, it's sending a stringified array, it seems. if you send a single object, it might not work..

Comment: @traynor Yes, this is addon for the browser as extension for other app. I'm looking for any way to add delays between requests (separate each element from array and send it 1 by 1 if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

in general, `forEach` should be replaced with `for..of` loop with using `async/await` helper function which will delay the request (in `await delaySome(1000);` part)

it should send data in the same format, and if it fails at the server, that's probably where it needs tweaking.. or everywhere else..

```
m = {
    mounted: function() {
        var e = this;
        this.$bus.on("buff-event", function(t) {
            e.buff(t);
        });
    },
    methods: {
        buff: function(e) {
            var t = this;


            function delaySome(delay) {
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve();
                    }, delay);
                });
            }

            this.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Motivating...");
            var n = '[{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[],"requestClass":"OtherPlayerService","requestMethod":"' + e + '","requestId":%%requestId%%}]';
            this.requestFaker.fetch(n).then(async function(i) {
                (i = (i = i.filter(function(t) {
                    return t.requestMethod == e;
                })[0]).responseData.filter(function(e) {
                    return void 0 === e.next_interaction_in && !e.is_self && (void 0 === e.accepted || 1 == e.accepted);
                })),
                (n = []);


                if (i.length) {
                    for (const e of i) {

                        await delaySome(1000);

                        t.requestFaker.fetch('[{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[' + e.player_id + '],"requestClass":"OtherPlayerService","requestMethod":"polivateRandomBuilding","requestId":%%requestId%%}]').then(function() {
                            t.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Motivation success");
                        })

                    }
                } else {
                    t.$bus.emit("bfceebecbb-change", "Nobody to motivate")
                }
            });
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: Unbelievable! It worked! Thank you so much! You managed to figure out this puzzle! :)

Comment: @Infinity great. minification is a one way road, you can't reverse it and make the code "pretty" again..